# How to send this type of parameter to server call in swift 3.0

Tags: ios, json, swift3

I need to send this below parameters to a server in swift 3.0. How can I build the request parameters?

```
"step_1": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "mobile": "",
            "line_1": "",
            "line_2": "",
            "city": "",
            "state": "",
            "pincode": "",
            "fax": "",
            "gst": "",
            "owner_name": "",
            "dob": "",
            "anniversary": ""
        }
    ]
```

Comment: what you have tried yet???

Comment: Use SwiftyJSON.

Comment: It depends on what kind of data the server expects.

Comment: I recommend you use [SwiftHTTP](https://github.com/daltoniam/SwiftHTTP) for a post request. It's pretty easy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For upper json data below is Dictionary code:

```
let param = [["name": "abc",
"mobile": "123",
"line_1": "line_1",
"line_2": "line_2",
"city":"xyz",
"state":"abc",
"pincode":"000",
"fax":"123",
"gst":"gst",
"ownwer_name":"ownwer_name",
"dob":"xx-xx-xxxx",
"anniversary":"xx-xx-xxxx"]]

//Print data
print(param[0]["name"] as! String)
```

Comment: Hi Sakir Sherasiya...Thanks for giving me answer.but it is not correct format as i shown upper data.the dictionary started with ' { 'curly braces.can you please check it once

Comment: You take step_1 as parent and all other are child right

Comment: Give me link of server

Comment: can you give example of parse query data

Comment: Use this [JSON Validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com) to make sure your json code is correct.

Answer (score -1):

Hi I'm not sure if it will work, but anyway, try this

```
let params: ["step_1": [["name": "Some name",
                  "mobile": "12345678",
                  "line_1": "line_1 stuff",
                  "...": "..."]]]
```